# remove "Uncaught exception on GetStream"

Tags: php, getstream-io

when the network is off-line, GetStream triggers an "Uncaught exception" error with a lot of detailed information on the code paths and structure.
How do I setup gestream so that no error message is printed in production?

```
Uncaught exception 'GetStream\Stream\StreamFeedException' with message 'user_id can only contain alphanumeric characters'
```

This is the full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException' 
with message 'cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 
out of 0 bytes received 
(see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' 
in /Sites/home-local/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:186 
Stack trace: #0 /Sites/homelocal/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(150):
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) 
#1 /Siteshome-local/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(103):
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), 
Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) 
#2 /Sites/home-local/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 186
```

Comment: the error message you added does not seem to be related to a network issue but to an invalid feed name.

Comment: thanks @TommasoBarbugli, however, this error only shows up when the network is down and not when the network is correctly working. In fact, when the network does working, getstream does what it is supposed to do.